# issue building Java class from xsd using JAXB

Tags: java, build, ant, xsd, jaxb

I am using ant to build my legacy project in which we generate Java class from XSD using JAXB and below is the ant config I have. JAXB parser is getting invoked properly and Java classes are getting created without any issue but ant stops building my project further after it invokes com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade class. Even the echo statement **message="Finished creating JAXB class"** doesn't get executed. I don't get any error message from ant build but it stops after creating the java classes. Not sure what the issue is; would really appreciate if someone could help me with this issue.

```
<target name="compile" >    
 <echo message="start creating JAXB class" />
    <java classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade"/">
        <arg value="input.xsd"/>
        <arg value="-b"/>
        <arg value="input.jxb"/> 
        <arg value="-d"/>
        <arg value="target.dir"/>

        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="classpath"/>
        </classpath>           
    </java>
   <echo message="Finished creating JAXB class" />
</target>
```

Comment: You have `}` after `input.jxb`, maybe this causes the problem?

Comment: JAXB2-Basics provides a working Ant project sample in [releases](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/releases/tag/0.11.1). Disclaimer: I'm the author of JAXB2-Basics.

Comment: extra } was a typo while posting the question. Edit my original post. Thanks